# How to get content between the div tags in C#

Tags: c#, regex

Code which wants to extract data:

```
<div class="Content">
    <div>
        <h3>Opening hours:</h3>

        <div>I want to get this text</div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I tried with this code:

```
Match OpeningHours = Regex.Match(data, "<h3>Opening hours:</h3>\n<div>(.+?)</div>");
if (OpeningHours.Success)
{
     string nOpeningHours = OpeningHours.Groups[1].Value;
     company.OpeningHours = nOpeningHours;
}
```

Comment: did you consider whitespaces, line breaks with the regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `\s*` after `\n`, so that the spaces or even line breaks after the `</h3>\n` got matched. `\s` matches any kind of vertical or horizontal white space character.

```
Regex.Match(data, @"<h3>Opening hours:</h3>\n\s*<div>(.+?)</div>");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vW6jU8/6)

Comment: The sample HTML contains TABs, not spaces. "Whitespace" might be a better term.

Comment: @PeterMortensen `\s` matches `\t` , `\n`, `\r` , \f`, etc